# Log SQL to file with logback & hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, logback

I am trying to get the SQL logged directly to a file when running the `dev` profile.
This is my logback.xml

```
<configuration>
<property name="SQL_LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${TMPDIR:-/tmp}}}/${HIBERNATE_LOG_FILE:-hibernate.log}"/>

<springProfile name="dev">
    <appender name="SQLDEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${SQL_LOG_FILE}</file>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>[%highlight(%p)] [%t] %c - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="SQLDEBUG"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" additivity="false" level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="SQLDEBUG"/>
    </logger>
</springProfile>

<root level="${logback.loglevel}">
    <springProfile name="dev">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </springProfile>
</root>
```

I have removed the `prod` profile settings for simplicity.
The `logger` for hibernate is inside the `dev` profile because I don't want it enabled in `prod`.
I have tried many combinations of these `org.hibernate` settings. This version generates SQL logs but only dumps them to console, not the log file. Some general startup information is added to the log file but no SQL.

If I change `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql` to `org.hibernate.type` there is a lot of stack trace logs that are added directly to the file, but no SQL.

Some posts recommend using `org.hibernate.SQL level=TRACE` but that did not seem to change anything.

I also tried putting the logger outside of the dev profile but that also did not change the results.

There is a lot of information for enabling logback & hibernate for simple console output but not for sending the SQL to its own log file.

I also tried enabling `hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` in IntelliJ but that makes a lot of SQL on the console, I need to not do that.

I have been try

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you spring profile is being used. To get this to work rename the logback.xml file to logback-spring.xml, allowing the springProfile tag to be used. In this tag, a name can be provided that can be set via properties, environment variables, or VM options. Below is how you can set the springProfile name to dev , which has been used to represent a development environment.

To set in application.properties or as an environment variable:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Or as a VM option:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Also, modify your root-level tag to be inside the spring profile tag:

```
     <springProfile name="dev">
       <root level="${logback.loglevel}">
          <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
       </root>
    </springProfile>
```